# Is it a good idea to mention in my CV, as a programmer, the number of reputation points on Stack Overflow?

Tags: resume, job-search, hiring-process, romania

I work in academia, as a lecturer, teaching computer programming and I am thinking of getting hired at a software firm. I was thinking to put in my CV my StackOverflow account, including how many reputation points I have (391 at the time of writing this post), as another proof of my competence.

Is it a good idea to do this? Does it mean anything to the recruiter, even if he didn't hear of this site before? Or should I omit it, because, unknowingly, I am giving him reasons to disqualify me?

Comment: Whoops. Didn't see that.

Comment: dear teacher, in romania, i don't think it matters that much

Comment: This is why I was asking. Don't know if here many people heard of it.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  The answer is surely "No" to this one.

Comment: Can you disclose the country/region that you are hunting in? Despite CV format being nearly universal unique, there's still some subtle cultural difference in what info and where to put them in CV.

Comment: Bucharest, Romania.

Comment: First points doesn't matter, and then 391 isn't really that much relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I was thinking to put in my CV my StackOverflow account, [...]*

Good idea.

> *[...] including how many reputation points I have*

Not so good.

Add the point that you have a profile at stackoverflow, and a regular there. Leave it at that. If your recruiter finds it interesting, they'll look up for you in SO.

In other words, you can add it, it does no harm, but make sure it gets added as one of those "extra" points (*"The things I also do" part*), not something which you want to be treated as "primary" skills.

After all, it's all about *imaginary internet points*. You have to prove your worth and / or capability in the actual interview.

Answer (score 2):

It's mixed bag.

On one side, it makes you look knowledgeable and helpful. On the other it might hint at you avoiding productivity by going on SO.

Comment: I can go on SO in my spare time.

Comment: You absolutely can, the question is, will a prospective employer know that?

Comment: Good question. You have a point.

Answer (score 2):

**Put it on.  Name and Rep Score**

One thing that comes up a lot in recruiting is "**what is your passion/hobby**", if you have a 4+ digit rep on a technology site that counts.

**It also lets me look up technical answers you've submitted.**  In theory this goes a long way towards letting me judge whether or not you're technically competent.

To be clear, this is a bonus, it won't help if you drop the ball somewhere else, but imho it's a really solid bonus for getting you to stand out.

Comment: BTW when I'm interviewing 50+ people over a 4 hour period, standing out is a really big deal.

Comment: Dark, OP's score is I think like a few hundred!

Comment: @Fattie I was assuming our new user was a sock puppet for a more advanced account.  If he doesn't have much of a rep then he shouldn't be trying to showcase his rep.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, instead of linking specifically to your SO account, create an [SO Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) account.

It's like a tech-based CV website, like LinkedIn, but pretty much only tech-related.

On the **SO Jobs** site you create the links to your SO profile and any other tech-related stuff you got (e.g. StackExchange, Github, Bitbucket, etc etc etc).

This gives you a single link which

- branches out (to other tech-related sites)
- personalized URI, e.g. mine: https://stackoverflow.com/story/robinkeet
- has a professional styling in both "story" and "traditional" view modes

As to mentioning the points you've accumulated: it's a mixed bag, because:

- a simple answer to a simple question can earn you thousands of points
- an answer which has stayed relevant for a long period (e.g. for JavaScript, CSS) earns a lot more over a longer period of time than a niche question/answer (e.g. for Yii, Zend Framework)

In my experience: if you look interesting enough on your CV that I continue to your SO Jobs/SE profile, then I'll look at some your big earner questions/answers.

---

Btw, judging from previous experience as Lead dev, looking at the CV's, doing the interviews, etc etc. Gone back to programming to broaden horizon :-)